# VS Code, Python, Intellisense and import module as

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

VS Code and Python Intellisense does not function when I import a "module as" such as:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import cv2
import cv2.aruco as aruco
```

I get intellisense clues when typing

```
cv2.aruco.***
```

I do not get clues when typing

```
aruco.***
```

Has anyone else experienced this before? Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me with the following code:

```
import importlib.abc as i_abc
i_abc.
```

You can also solve this by changing your import statement to `from cv2 import aruco`.